# Let $f:G→G'$ a homomorphism and let $K=\ker(f)$ and let $H$ an subgroup of $G$. Prove that: $f^{-1}(f(H))=HK=\{hk:h∈H,k∈K\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:G→G'$ a homomorphism and let $K=\ker(f)$ and let $H$ an subgroup of $G$. Prove that:

$$f^{-1}(f(H))=HK=\{hk:h∈H,k∈K\}$$

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f^{-1}(f(H)) = \{ x \in G : f(x) \in f(H) \} = \{ x \in G : \text{there is $h \in H$ such that $f(x) = f(h)$} \} = \dots$$

Answer (score 0):

By the first isomorphism theorem, we know that $G'\cong G/K.$ If we identify $G'$ and $G/K$, then $f(H)$ is the set of cosets $hK$ for $h\in H$. Now, what set in $G$ is mapped surjectively to this set of cosets?

> **More Deatils.**  If $g\in G$ is mapped to a coset $hK$, for $h\in H$, then $gK=hK$, that is to say, $g\in hK$, and so the preimage of $f(H)$ under $f$ is the set $HK$.

Inform me of any appearance of errors. Thanks.